# exception handling in cursors

Tags: oracle, exception, cursor

This question is not duplicate. (i m using oracle 10g)

I searched a lot but my problem seems to be diffrent

I have following cursor

```
DECLARE  
   -- Some declarations
   --
CURSOR C1 IS
   -- some select statements
Begin
    for r in c1 loop

        -- Insert queries
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERTED records');
    End loop;

EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
           dbms_output.put_line('error' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

As per the above cursor, whenever error occures during insert , error is printed on output and execution stops.
whereas It should continue looping.

I tried adding exception block inside loop but still not working

Comment: Please show us your other version where you tried to put the exception handling inside the loop.  That should have worked.

Answer (score 3):

Then you have to use another begin - exception - end within de loop. 
Something like this.

```
DECLARE  
   -- Some declarations
   --
CURSOR C1 IS
   -- some select statements
Begin
    for r in c1 loop

        BEGIN

            -- Insert queries
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERTED records');
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS 
            THEN
               dbms_output.put_line('error in LOOP' || SQLERRM);
        END;
    End loop;

EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('error' || SQLERRM);
END;
```